# White space issue with PHP

Tags: php, fieldset, removing-whitespace

I am accepting a preset input from another .php file

```
$Instructor=$_POST["Instructor"];
```

when I `echo $Instructor`, the OUTPUT is `Dr. Doom` (which is correct)

When i pass it through a fieldset I only get the (Dr.) and not the (Doom). I need for the entire name to get passed. Can any one please help. I am NEW TO PHP, so please try to explain in simple form. Thank you very much ahead of time.
here is the code i am using.

```
echo "<fieldset> 
 <Legend> Contact Information </Legend>
 PROFESSOR: <inputname='Professor' type= 'text' value=$Instructor maxlength='35' 
            disabled='disabled'> </fieldset>"
```

Comment: You CAN insert tags, just use the code button to format code and they will not disappear

Comment: @Mike B: he put the commas there because SO would not show tags in normal text (you have to put them as code). He explicitely wrote "the <,> cannot be inserted so please assume the syntax is correct". The error is the missing escaping, as you can see from the replies.

Comment: @nico Then it's NOT the code he's using (see my comment in Michael's answer) because absolutely nothing about it makes sense and would produce any kind of functionality. Vote to close as too localized.

Comment: @Mike B: you have the right to do so, although I disagree. The commas were there just because he did not know he could format the code, so he used them to trick SO engine. I don't see why one should make such a big fuss about this...

Answer (score 3):

Sincce you've omitted quotes on HTML attribute, only characters up to the first whitespace will be interpreted in your html.  Quote the attribute, and escape it properly with [`htmlentities()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) using the `ENT_QUOTES` option:

```
echo "<fieldset ... ... value='" . htmlentities($Instructor, ENT_QUOTES) . "' ... </fieldset>";
```

Note that without the escaping, it is vulnerable to cross-site scripting, in addition to potentially breaking the output markup.

Comment: @MikeB Huh? Of course the whitespace is important. The space in "Dr. Doom" is what causes the whole problem to begin with! And the question had `$Instructor` too, so I don't know why you complain about this answer having `$Instructor`.

Comment: @MrLister I mis-interepted the question before the mess was cleaned up in edits. The OP asked about removing white-space (look at the tag on the question) and I just had problems making heads or tails of it all (Why would removing white space help turn `Dr` into `Dr Doom`). I get the whole quoting attribute thing but the way his code started (look at revision 1) I had trouble understanding how it ever came close to working.

Comment: Oh... the "I only get the (Dr.) and not the (Doom)." bit was in the unedited question all along, which was the crux of the question, so I sort of overlooked the [removing-whitespace] tag.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put quotes around attribute values that contain spaces. In your case they need to be escaped, because the PHP string literal also uses them:

```
echo "... value=\"$Instructor\" ...";
```

Answer (score 1):

Variable sanitization aside, you forgot to quote this:

```
value=$Instructor
```

And mind the space here:

```
type= 'text'
```

By the way, There's a nice syntax in PHP called "[heredoc](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2003/04/10/php_heredocs.html)" if you want to use blocks of HTML text.

```
$str = <<<EOF
<fieldset> 
 <Legend> Contact Information </Legend>
 PROFESSOR: <inputname='Professor' type='text' value='$Instructor' maxlength='35' disabled='disabled'>
</fieldset>
EOF;
```

What's nice is the text can stay human readable and still support inline variable interpolation (putting "$something like this")

Comment: Please note that the space in `type= 'text'` is valid HTML. And putting quotes around `$Inspector` would make for valid HTML only if there are no quotes in the value of `$Inspector` itself.